# Xamarin.Forms Previewer "Connection is closed"

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, connection

Just opened the Xamarin.Forms Previewer and it says "Something went wrong, Connection is closed"
Its a fresh Visual Studio 2017 install and a blank Xamarin Forms Project.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hICqg.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I get this when I use the contentpage subclass popup pages from 3rd party library Rg.Plugins.Popup.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what worked for me.

1. Make sure `Android & Phone` are `selected` in XF previewer.
2. Now `Close` XF Previewer.
3. Make sure your `App.Android project is marked as the start up project`.
4. `Restart` VS
5. `Open` the previewer again.

I have no idea why the above worked for me, but, who am I to complain when its working.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Forms Previewer in Visual Studio 2019 contains several improvements, many focused on making it more reliable. Now that VS2019 is out, please try it. That should fix this issue and others.

Comment: I have same problem VS2019. Restart PC/VS not work.

Answer (score 0):

Same here with VS 2019 - 16.4.5. Happens over and over again... very annoying. For me its enough to close and reopen the xaml file.

You also may have a look here: https://windowsreport.com/something-went-wrong-connection-closed-xamarin/. And here are some troubleshooting tips from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows#troubleshooting)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem.
My problem was solved with Reinstall JDK11 on Windows
Download and install Jdk 11 of :
**https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5553-java-jdk.html**

Comment: Why would you download it from some shady third-party site rather than the official site? Are you affiliated with the site you link to?