# Good installation guide for Xamarin on VS2017

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I've got a new computer with Windows 10 and installed Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin (all via the Visual Studio 2017 installer in March 2018) all system requirements are more than matched. I can do some coding and it will run on the emulator. However, I wanted to use the Xamarin.Forms Previewer, which I can't use because of "there has been a problem. the connection is closed".
Furthermore I wanted to set up the Android Version to 6.0. I installed all the APIs down to Android 5.0) But I can't select an API other than API 25/Nougat 7.1. When I go to AVD I can't create a new device (OK button is disabled) because of "No CPU/ABI system image available for this target".

Can anyone give a good tutorial for the Xamarin and other needed installations/settings? I searched through YouTube but only found videos where everything is installed/set up already. I looked through some similar questions here on stackoverflow, however I think they're a little outdated (March 2016/May 2017).

Thanks for your help.
Thoms

=============================================

Update:
Following Billys links I could fix the Previewer issue (uninstalling any non 64-bit versions of java) and could set up the AVDs for the desired API-Levels (downloading CPU/ABI Images) --> Thanks Billy

However, on building I get the following warnings:

```
2>C:\Users\Thoms\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testXamarin3\testXamarin3\testXamarin3.Android\testXamarin3.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
2>C:\Users\Thoms\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testXamarin3\testXamarin3\testXamarin3.Android\testXamarin3.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
2>C:\Users\Thoms\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testXamarin3\testXamarin3\testXamarin3.Android\testXamarin3.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
```

Is there a way to get rid of those warnings without increasing the target framwork for my project (like decreasing the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll TargetFrameworkVersion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I wanted to use the Xamarin.Forms Previewer, which I can't use because of "there has been a problem. the connection is closed".

For this issue, I think you could try to update the jdk.
And you could refer to the following link:
[Xamarin.Forms Previewer "Connection is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530226/xamarin-forms-previewer-connection-is-closed)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85221/there-was-an-internal-issue-with-the-rendering-process
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78018/xamarin-forms-previewer-isnt-showing

> "No CPU/ABI system image available for this target"

This usually means some Image is not installed for the Api you selected.
For example ARM EABI v7a system Image and Intel x86 Atom System Image.

And it's better to use the new AVD Manager: [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager?tabs=vswin).
You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289125/xamarin-with-visual-studio-not-detecting-cpu-abi-system-image-for-emulator-even/48353792#48353792) for more infomration.

Here is the link for install the xamarin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows